# Swagger doesn't obtain PathVariable

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, swagger

I faced a problem using Swagger and Spring Boot. I have a method like this:

```
@ApiOperation(value = "Returns product of specified id")
@GetMapping("/{id}")
private ProductInShop getProduct(@ApiParam(name = "Product id", value = "Id of the product you want to get") @PathVariable String id) {
        return productService.findById(id);
    }
```

This operation works greatly in Postman and when I call `GET` method on my path and specify the id, I get needed product. But it doesn't work with swagger. I tried to debug and I observed that on this operation call id obtaines `'{id}'` value, not the product id. How can I solve this problem and make PathVariable to be fetched wrightfully?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem may be related with the `@ApiParam` `name` attribute: either get rid of it:

```java
@ApiOperation(value = "Returns product of specified id")
@GetMapping("/{id}")
private ProductInShop getProduct(@ApiParam(value = "Id of the product you want to get") @PathVariable String id) {
  return productService.findById(id);
}
```

Or provide the appropriate value:

```java
@ApiOperation(value = "Returns product of specified id")
@GetMapping("/{id}")
private ProductInShop getProduct(@ApiParam(name = "id", value = "Id of the product you want to get") @PathVariable String id) {
  return productService.findById(id);
}
```